# How can I install the latest Pantheon-files(0.3.xx) from (0.2.4) in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I read somewhere that it resolves the forward, backward problem. Is there a way without breaking the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need it, you might want to compile it from the source code with static linking to the newer libraries so that it does not mix up with the libraries already installed on your system.

If you need or will need in the foreseeable future more software updates than this one, you might just consider to install elementary OS 0.4 Loki.

Answer (score 0):

reddt said nope. https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/5ge82r/how_can_i_install_the_latest_pantheonfiles03xx/

If anyone decides to go ahead and try, do tell here, how it went.